# Expand date range to get all dates between series of date ranges from a table with excluded dates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to get all dates between `DATE_FROM` and `DATE_TO` of every `ID` of table `LEAVE` excluding weekends, work suspensions and holidays. Considering this record (`ID`, `DATE_FROM`, `DATE_TO`):

```
001   04-OCT-2018   09-OCT-2018
002   05-OCT-2018   05-OCT-2018
...
n     01-OCT-2018   05-OCT-2018
```

I need to get all the dates between those ranges in this format (`ID`, `DAY_TOKEN`):

```
001  04-OCT-2018
001  05-OCT-2018
001  08-OCT-2018
001  09-OCT-2018
002  05-OCT-2018
...
n    01-OCT-2018
n    02-OCT-2018
n    03-OCT-2018
n    04-OCT-2018
n    05-OCT-2018
```

I am using this query modified from the queries I found:

```
SELECT ID, a.date_from + rnum - 1 AS day_token
  FROM (SELECT a.ID, a.date_from, a.date_to, ROWNUM AS rnum
          FROM all_objects, leave a
          -- Aside from ALL_OBJECT, I cross join it with my LEAVE table
         WHERE ROWNUM <= a.date_to - a.date_from + 1) a
 WHERE TO_CHAR (a.date_from + rnum - 1, 'DY') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN');
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM holiday b
                    WHERE b.schedule = d.date_from + rnum - 1)
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM suspension c
                    WHERE c.schedule = d.date_from + rnum - 1)
```

The problem is that only the first record will expand properly and the other records will not be included in the record set unless the `DATE_FROM` and `DATE_TO` is of the same date.

I want to avoid using a PL-SQL function as much as possible, but if it's impossible to achieve the resultset I needed without using a function, please tell me at least the reason why.

Comment: Just one minor thing: You should avoid to use `TO_CHAR(., 'DY')` as this causes localization issues. Better use `TO_CHAR(., 'D')` instead.

Comment: Not an improvement, really, @Radagast81. ISO standard 8601 says that Monday is the first day of the week, Tuesday is the second (so your query would return "2" in Croatia and most of the world, as today is Tuesday). However, Canada, the USA, Australia, ... consider Sunday to be the first day of the week, so over there your query would return "3" (it is still Tuesday, right?). 'D' is controlled by NLS_TERRITORY, but can't be used in TO_CHAR function call; one should alter session. Though, yes - NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE might be used in TO_CHAR and would handle that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to create as many rows for each ID as there are days between FROM and TO dates, without weekends (Saturdays and Sundays):

```
SQL> with leave (id, date_from, date_to) as
  2  (select '001', date '2018-10-04', date '2018-10-09' from dual union all
  3   select '002', date '2018-10-05', date '2018-10-05' from dual union all
  4   select '003', date '2018-10-02', date '2018-10-08' from dual
  5  ),
  6  inter as
  7    (select l.id,
  8       l.date_from + column_value datum,
  9       to_char(l.date_from + column_value, 'day') day
 10     from leave l,
 11          table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 12                              connect by level <= l.date_to - l.date_from + 1
 13                             ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 14    )
 15  select id, datum
 16  from inter
 17  where to_char(datum, 'dy') not in ('sat', 'sun');

ID  DATUM
--- -----------
001 05-oct-2018
001 08-oct-2018
001 09-oct-2018
001 10-oct-2018
003 03-oct-2018
003 04-oct-2018
003 05-oct-2018
003 08-oct-2018
003 09-oct-2018

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

As line 18 (and so forth), add additional conditions (remove holidays, suspensions, whatever).

(BTW, I wonder who & why downvoted your question; it is well-formed, shows what you have, your attempt to solve it ... really, a mystery to me).